# mysql query is not giving me the right output

Tags: php, mysql

My query is giving me a fixed number '2' even when I choose an event made by different user.

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT e.user_id 
    FROM ".$table_prefix."events e
    WHERE EXISTS 
        (
            SELECT email 
            FROM ".$table_prefix."users u 
            WHERE e.user_id = u.user_id
        )
    ");
    $li = mysql_fetch_row($q);    
    echo $li;
```

what's wrong?

Comment: you might wana change that `echo` to a `print_r` anddddddddd add some debugging as if your query even executed?

Comment: Don't blame mysql, blame your code... also: Don't use the _deprecated_ `mysql_*` extension. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_*`. Go to any doc-page of any `mysql_*` function and _read_ the big, red box saying __warning__, it's there for a reason. PS: read up on `JOIN`

Comment: In your sql there no proper condition to select a particular row of user.

Comment: where is the part where your pass event or user as a param to where clause? this looks to me like a static query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql="SELECT e.id 
FROM USER e
WHERE EXISTS 
(
 SELECT email 
FROM student u 
WHERE e.id = u.user_id
)";

$gosql=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($gosql)){

    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($row);
}


or you can use

$sql="SELECT e.id 
FROM USER e
WHERE EXISTS 
(
 SELECT email 
FROM student u 
WHERE e.id = u.user_id
)";

$gosql=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($gosql)){

    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($row);
}
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2):

EXISTS returns true if the statement inside returns records, false if there are no rows.

your not passing or using your user id variable anywhere in the statement.

I prefer your query into an inner join:

```
SELECT 
    events.userid
FROM 
    events INNER JOIN users
    ON events.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE
    users.userid = ?? -- ur passed userid
```

Answer (score 0):

You  have to change the

```
echo $li;
```

to

```
print_r($li);
```